# How to select TOP 'n' rows with unique values and the highest amounts in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I am working in SSMS v17.6 and I need to gather top 3 rows per unique "ID" and "FRUIT" with the highest values as below.

EXAMPLE DATA

```
ID  FRUIT   OTHER_ID    VALUE 
GG-1    APPLE   25432   100
GG-1    APPLE   37586   200
GG-1    APPLE   33614   400
GG-1    APPLE   70776   500
GG-1    APPLE   52102   600
GG-2    BANANA  33745   150
GG-2    BANANA  44823   250
GG-2    BANANA  88313   350
GG-2    BANANA  25181   450
GG-2    BANANA  65301   650
```

RESULT (top 3)

```
ID  FRUIT   OTHER_ID    VALUE       
GG-1    APPLE   33614   400
GG-1    APPLE   70776   500
GG-1    APPLE   52102   600
GG-2    BANANA  88313   350
GG-2    BANANA  25181   450
GG-2    BANANA  65301   650
```

The data is not limited to the two fruits and IDs displayed in this example but each fruit has unique ID. I think it can be done based just on ID itself. In my mind the `SELECT TOP(n)` wouldn't work and neither would `Order By ... LIMIT n`

Perhaps some sort of a rank function would do it but I am not sure of the terminology necessary here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, fruit order by VALUE desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 3;
```

Comment: ORDER BY clause needs a column to be mentioned. I think you have missed to add it.

Comment: Thank you, this actually steered me in the right direction. Problem solved !

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis . . . I know that it has worse performance characteristics.

Comment: Really? Got any links for this?